# Erlang VM: scheduler runtime information

Tags: erlang, profiling, scheduler

I was searching for a way to retrieve information about how the scheduling is done during a program's execution: which processes are in which scheduler, if they change, what process is active at each scheduler, if each scheduler runs in one core etc...

Any ideas or related documentation/articles/anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look on the following tracing/profiling options:

[erlang:system_profile/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_profile-0)

It has options for monitoring scheduler and run queue (runnable_procs) activity.
The scheduler option will report

```
{profile, scheduler, Id, State, NoScheds, Ts}
```

where State will tell you if it is active or not. NoScheds reports the number of currently active schedulers (if I remember correctly).

The runnable_procs option will let you know if a process is put into or removed from a run queue of a particular scheduler.

Comment: thanks! I had R14A and it always return undefined but I upgraded to R14B04 and it works fine now :D

Comment: the process is active when it's on the run queue, not only when it actually runs, right?

Comment: Yes, It is deemed active both when it is runnable (in the run queue) or actually running and inactive otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a system that supports DTrace, you can use the erlang dtrace probes being developed to see exactly when process scheduling events occur.

For example, I wrote a [simple one-liner](https://gist.github.com/6f73df27f67a7d123e63) that shows you the number of nanoseconds that pass between sending a message to a process and having the recipient process be scheduled for execution (± a few nanoseconds for cross-core clock variance and processes and such).

Comment: I like dtrace, too bad it only works on mac and solaris (and a few others) but not linux. @Dustin, good work on the erlang/dtrace impl.

Comment: systemtap kind of works for doing the same stuff.  You can always work on something that isn't Linux or Windows enough to figure out how things work and then apply that knowledge back on your Linux deployment.

Comment: interesting, I will definitely check DTrace/SystemTrap!